# Getting JSON parsing error (MismatchedInputException) in Spring Rest Controller

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson, spring-restcontroller

I am quite new to Spring. I am having a JSON parsing error when I try a POST method in Postman. Basically, I have a class that I want to call in another one in the form of a list.

I have an abstract entity that I use for classes, then I have a tag class;

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Tag extends AbstractEntity {

    @Column (nullable = false)
    private String tag;
```

And I have a question class:

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Question extends AbstractEntity {

    @Column (nullable = false)
    private String title;
    @Column (nullable = false)
    private String content;
    @OneToMany
    @Column (nullable = false)
    private List<Tag> tag;
```

Here is my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("v1/enquiry")
public class EnquiryController {

    @Autowired
    private QuestionRepository questionRepository;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Question> createEnquiry(@RequestBody Question question) {
        if (question.getTitle() == null | question.getContent() == null) {
            throw new BadRequest("Please fill in the required fields!");
        }

        Question enq = questionRepository.save(question);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(enq);
    }
```

When I do a POST method with:

```
{ 
   "title": "question",
   "content": "cogito",
   "tag": ["java", "rest"]
}
```

I get the following error. I quite tried all of the suggestions to similar conditions posted around. None of them worked. What am I doing wrong?

> "message": "JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.mockup.mockupapi.model.Tag` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('java'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.mockup.mockupapi.model.Tag` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('java')\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 4, column: 10] (through reference chain: com.mockup.mockupapi.model.Question[\"tag\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])",

---

> **SOLVED**

Thanks to clues in the commentary, I changed the array format in JSON, and added `CascadeType` to `OneToMany` call. I used `.PERSIST`, however, `.ALL` works as well.

The JSON format:

```
{ 
   "title": "question",
   "content": "cogito",
   "tag": [{"tag":"java"},{"tag": "rest"}]
}
```

The Question class:

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Question extends AbstractEntity {

    @Column (nullable = false)
    private String title;
    @Column (nullable = false)
    private String content;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @Column (nullable = false)
    private List<Tag> tag;
```

Comment: What happens if you add a `@NoArgsConstructor` to `Tag`?

Comment: I tried, however, I still get the same error, with the same message output. @user991710

Comment: Change your JSON to this "tag":[{"tag":"java"},{"tag":"rest"}]. Specifically for that tag key.

Comment: I actually tried versions like `"tag":{"java","rest"}` and other possible versions. However, this one throws a `IllegalStateException` error: `save the transient instance before flushing`. @gnanajeyam95

Comment: Then add cascade type to ur one to many mapping

Comment: You might also try adding `@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@JsonCreator))` to your `Tag` object. That should allow deserialization from the json structure you initially had. I believe `@Data` only adds a `@RequiredArgsConstructor`, which is no-arg for your `Tag` object. Even better would be to make the `name` field final, but I'm not sure if the rest of your code allows that.

Comment: You might also try adding `@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@JsonCreator))` to your `Tag` object. That should allow deserialization from the json structure you initially had. I believe `@Data` only adds a `@RequiredArgsConstructor`, which is no-arg for your `Tag` object. Even better would be to make the `name` field final, but I'm not sure if the rest of your code allows that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change your JSON structure.

```
{ "title": "question", "content": "cogito", "tag": [{"tag":"java"},{"tag": "rest"}] }
```

Also add cascade in your mapping.

```
@OneToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @Column (nullable = false) 
 private List<Tag> tag;
```